# can we predict the json data in R?

Tags: json, r, prediction

I'm working on R language and tired to predict the json data using XGBoost model.I'm working with temperature dataset which contains eight variables [temperature dataset with eight variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qqLK.png) but R can take only four variables [R takes four variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObPNv.png). I want to build a model by taking temperture and humidity but it doesn't take those variables.
can anyone help me?

Comment: please post code for data conversion from JSON object to dataframe. Looks like there is some problem

Comment: library(jsonlite)
data <- fromJSON("dataset.json", flatten=FALSE)

Comment: some sample data as well to reproduce your issue.

Comment: [
{
"id": "0457483d1e64ed9ce7b176ef87042c14",
"key": "0457483d1e64ed9ce7b176ef87042c14",
"value":{
"rev": "1-ef74539f91c4fe9e736d0d0b7c555a8a"},
"doc": {"_id": "0457483d1e64ed9ce7b176ef87042c14",
"_rev": "1-ef74539f91c4fe9e736d0d0b7c555a8a",
"topic":"iot-2/type/iotqs-sensor/id/3b67c7b9492c/evt/iotsensor/fmt/json","payload": {"d": {
"name": "3b67c7b9492c","temp": 43,
"humidity": 63,"objectTemp": 38}},"deviceId": "3b67c7b9492c","deviceType": "iotqs-sensor",
"eventType": "iotsensor",
"format": "json"}} ]

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the sub elements in json data we need to use "$".
For example for the above data we have to use "data$doc" to get the eight variables.
train<-data$doc
[click here it contains the eight variables in train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWHed.png)